# gulp karma issue browser never start

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

I have 
`node 4.4.3`
`npm 3.8.6`
`protractor: 3.2.2` installed globally
`gulp 3.9.1` installed globally and locally with a link

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
        "connect": "3.4.1",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "1.2.0",
        "gulp-protractor": "2.1.0",
        "serve-static": "1.10.2",
        "karma":"0.13.22",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8"
    }
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
var  Server = require('karma').Server;

gulp.task('test3', function (done) {
Server.start({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'

    }, done);
});
```

when I run the task the only feedback i get is

```
[11:10:03] Starting 'test3'...

21 04 2016 11:10:04.008:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

21 04 2016 11:10:04.016:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
```

Then it waits forever

When I run the task the "old" way:

```
 var karma = require('karma').server;
    var karmaConf = require('./karma.conf.js')();
    karma.start(karmaConf, done);
```

It works fine

I do have a correctly configured karma.conf.js.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it
my karma.conf.js was like this

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {...};
};
```

and I made changes to make it like this

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set( { ....
```

this made it work

Comment: I already have the below format but it is still not launching the browsers.